# Lifting one side of text - Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, transform

I'm trying to lift the right side of my text, so it is similar to text in this logo:

[image]

I've tried different kinds of warps, but can't find the right one. Maybe I should be looking at another effect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using Object -> Envelope Distort -> Make with Mesh, with the following result:

[image]

This is the desired effect (but needs some tweaking of course).

Answer (score 1):

You can use "type on path" feature [to create any wavy](http://vectips.com/tips/type-on-a-path-options/) texts you want.

Comment: Hi, you added the answer when I was writing my own answer, so I had to try out yours first. However, the problem with `type on path` is that it doesn't really alter the shape of the letters, not enough to my liking at least. This is why I will mark my answer as accepted answer. Your solution is faster though, so it's just up to how much time you have I guess and how important the result is.

Comment: @Rvervuurt i've read you want to rise some part of the text, not perform distortion... There are many ways to affect the shapes in the way you want

Comment: Yes, I know I said rising. I didn't know I was actually looking to distort the text :)